# How do windows executables run on both AMD CPUs and Intel CPUs?

Tags: cpu

Do they contain instructions for both CPUs or do the CPUs have the same instruction set?

Assuming they weren't compiled to an intermediate language (although even then, I think the intermediate language compiler has one version for both CPUs).

Comment: It's a [mixed-up world](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64).

Comment: What do you mean by "Intel CPUs"? Intel builds CPUs with *at least* two different instruction sets: AMD64 and ARM.